# Incompatibility between training and test data in a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, train-test-split

**I am using R version 4.2.2 in RStudio version 2022.12.0+353 on an M1 Macbook Air running MacOS 13.0.1**

I am a medical doctor performing modelling on data from patients who have stayed in an Intensive Care Unit I work in (I have full ethical approval etc and no results obtained will be used to treat future patients).

When patients are extremely unwell they can be turned face down ('the prone position'). I am working on a logistic regression model to give the likelihood of death within 72 hours based on how a patient responds to this maneuver.

I have successfully trained a (not hugely accurate) model on some training data but am encountering an error message when I try to make predictions with the testing data.

The original dataframe consists of 23 variables and 365 observations. In order to create a train/test split I used `initial_split()` from the `rsample` package.

```
# die_in_72 is a true/false variable showinbg if the patient did or did not die within 72hrs

mort_72_data <- initial_split(predict_mortality_changes72, 
                              prop = 0.8, 
                              strata = die_in_72)
```

There were a small amount of NAs. I imputed them using the `mice` package:

```
imputed_mort_72 <- mice(data = mort_72_data_train,
                        method = 'pmm', 
                        m = 100)

mort_72_data_train_imputed <-  complete(imputed_mort_72)
```

I have trained a logistic regression model using 3 of the variables that lasso regression showed to be relevant.

```
lr_model_01 <- glm(data = mort_72_data_train_imputed,
                   formula = die_in_72 ~ 
                     pfr_change_absolute +
                     apache_ii +
                     time_between_abg,
                   family = 'binomial')
```

I have successfully used the model to predict this outcome from the training data. Accuracy is not optimal yet (but I have some idea why and what to do about it).

```
pred_model_01 <- select(mort_72_data_train, die_in_72)

pred_model_01$prediction_response <- predict(object = lr_model_01, 
                                             newdata = mort_72_data_train_imputed, 
                                             type = 'response')
```

The problem comes when I try to make predictions on the testing data. I get an error message. Here is how I have tried to make new predictions:

```
mort_72_data_test <- testing(mort_72_data)

pred_model_01$prediction_response_2 <- predict(object = lr_model_01,
                                               newdata = mort_72_data_test,
                                               type = 'response')
```

The error message I get describes an incompatibility between data. I am absolkutely stumped. Here is the error message.

```
Error:
! Assigned data `predict(object = lr_model_01, newdata = mort_72_data_test, type = "response")` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 291 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 74 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
  1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, prediction_response_2, value = `<dbl>`)
 12. tibble (local) `<fn>`(`<vctrs___>`)
```

Can anyone who can shed any light on why this is happening? I have made predictions in other contexts and cannot see what is going wrong here.

Comment: You are assinging both test and train predictions to `pred_model_01`. Since test and train have a different number of outcomes, you cannot really directly assign both the the same data.frame.I guess if you run just the predict on it's own `predict(object = lr_model_01, newdata = mort_72_data_test, type = 'response')` it probably runs fine, it's just the assignment to a data.frame of the wrong size that's causing the problem.

Comment: Oh wow, I was totally fixated on the wrong part of this. I get it now,. It's so simple. Thanks for helping me see the light!